# Mobile Automation with appium -- Selenium driver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, appium, serenity-bdd

I am trying to execute a test in mobile device, but i am having the next error

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new
>   remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original
>   error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the
>   command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate
>   Chrome '83.0.4103'. You could also try to enable automated
>   chromedrivers download server feature. See
>   https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md
>   for more details Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision:
>   'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host:
>   'DESKTOP-3EOJTAA', ip: '169.254.34.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch:
>   'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91' Driver info:
>   driver.version: AndroidDriver remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An
>   unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome
>   '83.0.4103'. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers
>   download server feature. See
>   https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md
>   for more details
>       at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\wilso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
>       at asyncHandler (C:\Users\wilso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:392:37)
>   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
>   '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'DESKTOP-3EOJTAA', ip:
>   '169.254.34.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91' Driver info: driver.version:
>   AndroidDriver     at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:84)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:94)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:95)
>     at
>   Appium.com.appium.utilities.Configuration.initConfiguration(Configuration.java:31)
>     at
>   Appium.com.appium.principal.Principal.testSeventhWithBrowser(Principal.java:117)
>     at Appium.com.appium.principal.Principal.main(Principal.java:29)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
>     ... 15 more Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An
>   unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome
>   '83.0.4103'. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers
>   download server feature. See
>   https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md
>   for more details Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision:
>   'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host:
>   'DESKTOP-3EOJTAA', ip: '169.254.34.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch:
>   'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91' Driver info:
>   driver.version: AndroidDriver remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An
>   unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome
>   '83.0.4103'. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers
>   download server feature. See
>   https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md
>   for more details
>       at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\wilso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
>       at asyncHandler (C:\Users\wilso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:392:37)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>     at
>   java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
>     ... 20 more

Chrome version:
83.04103.101

[image]

I am searching solutions, but i haven't found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you develop script on Android Chrome, If you are control android chrome, you can check the chrome driver version in appium whether it is matched with android chrome version on your device. The chrome driver in appium should store the location like this:

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win.
```

This is the windows appium lcoation. Drag the chromedriver.exe into CMD, you can see the driver version.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your log(**Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '83.0.4103'. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers download server feature**) means you have chromedriver browser compatibilities issue, the chromedriver in your mobile emulator and the chromedriver appium has is mismatch. To fix this issue, you need to follow below steps:

1. Download chromedriver version 83.0.4103, you can find it here https://chromedriver.chromium.org/
2. Delete existing appium chromedriver, which locate in this path if Windows(C:\Users\yourUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win)
3. Copy& paste the chromedriver version(83.0.4103) you downloaded
4. Run your test again